# Windows Mobile - Write to Application Data folder

Tags: windows-mobile

I want to write some image files to the "Application Data" folder on a Windows Mobile from my application so they can be used by other applications too.

Is this possible? Or is the file system sandboxed for WinMo?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SHGetSpecialFolderPath function to get the path to these kind of folder. You can find the reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa453707.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. I understand I have to use CSIDL_APPDATA. Do I have to specify the HWND value if I just want the path and don;t need to show a dialog box?

Comment: You can set hwndOwner to NULL in this case.